# Getting Commerce Products using Element API in Craft 3

Tags: plugin-elementapi, plugin-craftcommerce2

I am trying to get Products using the Element API plugin. I set the 'elementType' to `Commerce_Products`, `CommerceProducts`, etc.., but the endpoint keeps returning:

> Endpoint has an invalid elementType

This is my endpoint:

```
use craft\commerce\elements\Product as ProductsModel;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'api/search' => [
            'elementType' => 'ProductsModel',
            'paginate' => false,
            'pretty' => true,
            'criteria' => [
                'limit' => 15,
                'search' => (Craft::$app->request->getParam('keyName')) ? 'title:'.'*'.Craft::$app->request->getParam('keyName').'*' : ''
            ],
            'transformer' => function(ProductsModel $product) {
                return [
                    'title' => $product->title,
                    'url' => $product->url
                ];
            },
        ],
    ]
];
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: How can i return image url for product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're so close! Just one change (see the `elementType` key, and the added comment)…

```
use craft\commerce\elements\Product;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'api/search' => [
            'elementType' => Product::class, // This provides Element API the fully qualified Element namespace + class.
            'paginate' => false,
            'pretty' => true,
            'criteria' => [
                'limit' => 15,
                'search' => (Craft::$app->request->getParam('keyName')) ? 'title:'.'*'.Craft::$app->request->getParam('keyName').'*' : ''
            ],
            'transformer' => function(Product $product) {
                return [
                    'title' => $product->title,
                    'url' => $product->url
                ];
            },
        ],
    ]
]
```

> **Note:** I'd recommend leaving the `use` statement as just `Product`, as I've done above. What you're importing is a class that inherits from the Craft `Element` class… “Model” has some other specific connotations in Craft + Yii, and even though at a lower level, Elements are still models, I think it's a good idea to leave them named as-is… after all, this is the *Element* API!

Comment: For those curious folks out there, this is effectively no different than providing a string `'craft\commerce\elements\Product'`, but Craft 3 seems to express a pretty strong preference for the `::class` constant, instead.